# How can I ensure a consistent url "interface" between different controllers in an Asp.net MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, url-routing

Interfaces in C# are great to ensure my controllers' action methods take the same number, data type and order of parameters. Unfortunately, that doesn't help keep the urls generated by the routing mechanism consistent. How can I ensure the *names* of parameters are the same?

For example:

How do I ensure that

```
sportswear/products
```

and

```
carsandtrucks/products
```

both take the parameter `productId`?

I'd like to try to avoid a lot of routes in global.asax.cs, as I feel that they're not intuitive, but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Please give an example of what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that the best option would be a unit test that finds all implementations of your controller interfaces and ensures that the implementation parameter names match those on the interface.

So something like

```
public interface IController
{
    ActionResult GetProducts(string productId);
}

[TestFixture]
public class IControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void EnsureImplementationsUseCorrectParameterNames()
    {
        // Assuming all required assemblies have been loaded
        var implementations = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
        var interfaceMethods = typeof(IController).GetMethods().ToList();

        foreach (var implementation in implementations)
        {
            var methodPairs = interfaceMethods.Join(implementation.GetMethods(), mi => mi.ToString(), mi => mi.ToString(), (inner, outer) => new { InterfaceMethod = inner, ImplementationMethod = outer });
            foreach (var methodPair in methodPairs)
            {
                using (var interfaceParameters = methodPair.InterfaceMethod.GetParameters().Cast<ParameterInfo>().GetEnumerator())
                using (var implementationParameters = methodPair.ImplementationMethod.GetParameters().Cast<ParameterInfo>().GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (interfaceParameters.MoveNext() && implementationParameters.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual(interfaceParameters.Current.Name, implementationParameters.Current.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting approach. Could see this even as a qunit suite :)